# Symfony Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.42

Tags: composer-php, symfony-2.3

When i run composer update with the json file below I get this error

```
   Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.42
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.42
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.41
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.1
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle dev-master requires symfony/doctrine-bridge ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/doctrine-bridge[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9].
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v2.7.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.0
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.3.0].
    - symfony/doctrine-bridge v3.3.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v2.3.0].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[dev-master].
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/translation-bundle": "1.2.2",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to raise symfony/symfony to at least 2.7.0

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
```

to:

```
"symfony/symfony": "^2.3",
```

This will allow to install newer versions than 2.3 (actually 2.3 >=), but will be compatible with rest of dependencies.

Comment: A whole afternoon lost until your answer appeared!

Comment: Sometimes it's a whole week... or believe in happy end :D
I recommend using one version for all the vendor packages. E.g. for symfony/* I have ^5.0 everywhere now.